Resolving variable scope in Python Gurobi constraint summations
I would like to add the following constraint to my model:
model.addConstrs(
   (grb.quicksum(x[i, n] for n in N) ==
    grb.quicksum((1 - y[i, m]) * z[i, m] for m in [x for x in N if x != n])
    for i in I), name=""
    )

The code will not work because the variable "n" is not visible outside the first quicksum().
I would be grateful for a tip on how to redefine the constraint.

Can you write the math of what you want rather than code?

Heyy bro, one way to get around this is to create a copy of the N list for the second quicksum(). N.copy() creates a new copy of the N list that is independent of the first one. This allows you to use the variable ‘n’ in the second quicksum

Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, I think this will not solve my problem (if I got it right). The variable 'n' is defined in the first quicksum() so I cannot access it in the second one.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
